Connecting my headphones via Bluetooth makes my Bluetooth mouse stutter/jitter. How can I reduce the stuttering/jittering?
Whenever I connect my headphones via Bluetooth, it makes my Bluetooth mouse stutter/jitter. How can I reduce the stuttering/jittering?
My config: MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop with Win 10 and these devices:


Bluetooth has very limited bandwidth (~2Mbps) that it must share among all connected devices. The best solution is to not use a bluetooth headset. Get a headset with a high-bandwidth (proprietary) wireless protocol.

@Mokubai thanks, this is great information, you're welcome to post it as an answer

Just from experience, with 3 personal computers and 1 work computer, a combination of desktops and laptops, I have never observed this issue.  I usually have 2 different headsets (sometimes 3), and both a keyboard and mouse using BT all at the same time. This is also with a combination of built-in BT radios and cheap USB BT dongles. What I can say from all this experience is that your experience is abnormal, and the normal steps of updating drivers and firmware should be done on your computer AND the BT accessories. If that doesn't work, get a USB BT dongle and try using that instead.
